# multiple versions of dll for WCF service with two services exposed

Tags: .net, wcf, dll, versioning

I have 2 wcf projects in the same solution. both reference libraryX, but use different versions. when deployed, both services are in the same folder with the same bin folder, so I have an issue with both DLLs being called libraryX.dll. Internally, they have a different version, so can I just rename the physical filename of one? If not, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the RelativeSearchPath for the current AppDomain by changing the PrivateBinPath on the AppDomainSetup.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx

And move the older (or newer) assembly file to a subfolder under your application base.

so have a structure like:
c:\myapp\bin [all curent files]
c:\myapp\bin\older [the older library]

In code:

```
AppDomain.CurentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = "older";
```